# Adding labels to a legend with dynamic colours

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, json, d3.js

I'm currently producing a multi-line graph using d3.js. I'm currently looking to produce a simple legend that describes each lines Client name and its line colour by styling the font in its corresponding colour in the graph.

My test data looks something like this:

```
var data = [{
                    "Client": "ABC",
                    "sale": "202",
                    "time": "09:00"
                }, {
                    "Client": "ABC",
                    "sale": "215",
                    "time": "11:00"
                }, {
                    "Client": "ABC",
                    "sale": "179",
                    "time": "12:00"
                }, {
                    "Client": "ABC",
                    "sale": "199",
                    "time": "13:00"
                }, {
                    "Client": "ABC",
                    "sale": "134",
                    "time": "15:00"
                }, {
                    "Client": "ABC",
                    "sale": "176",
                    "time": "16:00"
                }, {
                    "Client": "ABC",
                    "sale": "197",
                    "time": "17:00"
                }, {
                    "Client": "XYZ",
                    "sale": "100",
                    "time": "09:00"

                ...etc

                }];
```

By using d3.nest(), I've sorted the json by its Client name which now produces the data shown below:

```
[{
"key": "ABC",
"values": [{
    "Client": "ABC",
    "sale": "202",
    "year": "2000"
}, {
    "Client": "ABC",
    "sale": "215",
    "year": "2002"
}, {
    "Client": "ABC",
    "sale": "179",
    "year": "2004"
}, {
    "Client": "ABC",
    "sale": "199",
    "year": "2006"
}, {
    "Client": "ABC",
    "sale": "134",
    "year": "2008"
}, {
    "Client": "ABC",
    "sale": "176",
    "year": "2010"
}]
}, {
    "key": "XYZ",
    "values": [{
        "Client": "XYZ",
        "sale": "100",
        "year": "2000"
    }, { ...etc
```

The new json I've produced above is called 'dataGroup'. I'm trying to use iteration to populate a div on my DOM with client names in their respective colours I've given them using d3.scale.category10();

Here is my current code for the div:

```
dataGroup.forEach(function(d, i){

        d3.select("#value")
            .append("text")
            .data(dataGroup)
            .style("color", function(d, i){
                return colours(i);
            })
            .text(function(d){
                return d.key;
            });
    });
```

So far, all this does is return the first Client (ABC) and then stops. To my understanding, I thought d3 would've iterated through all the keys in the dataGroup but it hasn't. I've tried putting a for loop in the text function but that hasn't helped either.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem here. D3 will iterate, if you bind the data properly. This is how you can do:

First, select the div or span you want:

```
var clientText = d3.select("#value");
```

Then, create a variable for the texts, and bind the data from `dataGroup` in this order:

```
var texts = clientText.selectAll(".clients")
  .data(dataGroup)
  .enter()
  .append("text");
```

We call this a "select-data-enter-append" sequence.

Then, you can do the rest of your code:

```
texts.style("color", function(d, i){
            return colors(i);
        })
        .text(function(d){
            return d.key;
        });
```

This will print all the names in sequence, not the most beatiful result.

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uwLcrzxk/

Comment: Ok, I tried this method, replacing the "#svganchor" with the name of my divs class (In this case "#value") but now nothing is appearing in the legend. Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry for that ID, my bad, I am writing 3 codes at the same time. All the keys were printed to me. Please notice that I wrote "colors" where you have "colours". Can you share a working plunker or jsfiddle?

Comment: Its not working I'm afraid. The desired output is supposed to be the 3 different clients from the data, i.e. ABC, XYZ and PQR. So far, its only displaying ABC 3 times.

Comment: @MarkO'Hare, I'm terrible sorry, I was doing several things at the same time. My bad. I updated my answer, its working now.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving `.data(dataGroup)` before the `.append("text")`, and adding `.enter()`, like so:

```
d3.select("#value")
            .data(dataGroup)
            .enter()
            .append("text")
            .style("color", function(d, i){
                return colours(i);
            })
            .text(function(d){
                return d.key;
            });
```

Comment: That didn't seem to make a difference. Its still only picking up the first key

Comment: Have you tried using `enter()`, like @Gerardo mentioned? I updated my answer with that line as well.

Comment: Now you have a better select-data-enter-append pattern.

Comment: Adding the .enter() causes nothing to appear in the div at all it seems.